# How can I understand the proof of integer divisibility?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, proof-explanation

The context is the book, *An Introduction to The Theory of Numbers*, by Ivan Niven, Herbert S. Zuckerman, and Hugh L. Montgomery.

Theorem 1.2 says

> The division algorithm. Given any integers $a$ and $b$, with $a>0$, there exist unique integers $q$ and $r$ such that $b=qa+r$, $0\leq r<a$. If $a\nmid b$, then $r$ satisfies the stronger inequalities $0<r<a$.

Theorem 1.1 part 5 says

> $a \mid b$, $a>0$, $b>0$, imply $a\leq b$

## Understanding the Proof

> To prove the uniqueness of $q$ and $r$, suppose there is another pair $q_1$ and $r_1$ satisfying the same conditions. First we prove that $r_1 = r$. For if not, we may presume that $r<r_1$ so that $0<r_1-r<a$, and **we see that** $r_1 -r=a(q-q_1)$, and so $a|(r_1-r)$, a contradiction to Theorem 1.1, part 5. Hence $r=r_1$, and also $q=q_1$.

First of all, **I do not see** anything. Am I an idiot for not seeing this? Help me to see what "we" all see according to Ivan'n'Herbert'n'Hugh using a more verbose explanation (I am a person of words). This recognition seems essential to understanding the proof, but the book brushes over quickly and moves on to the next theorem.

Comment: We have $b=qa+r$, so that $r=b-qa$. Similarly, $r_1=b-q_1a$. Now it should be clear.

Comment: Apparently, in the writing style of this book, “we see that” means “it has not been mentioned before, but if you try until you find the right way to combine the equations already shown, you should be able to work out the fact that”. That’s fairly typical for a math textbook; it can take quite a while just to read and understand a few pages.

Comment: @DavidK That is why I dislike math textbooks. Most things are not apparent to me as they are to others, it would seem. It is a shame, because I respect the power of math. Sometimes things hit me like, "WHOA, is it really that easy?" and I feel good about it. Those times are few in number. http://discovermagazine.com/2014/jan-feb/39-some-have-a-head-for-math

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $b=qa+r$ and $b=q_1a+r_1$, you have\begin{align}r_1-r&=(b-q_1a)-(b-qa)\\&=(q-q_1)a\end{align}and therefore $a\mid r_1-r$.

Comment: The book says something else: $r_1 -r = a(q -q_1)$, not $r_1 -r = a(q_1-q)$. Could you please explain your answer in more words to justify its logic? You also did not delve into the contradiction. As it stands, I cannot accept your answer.

Comment: @JonathanKomar I've edited my answer. I hope that everything is clear now.

Comment: You skipped a few steps, which make it yet unclear. Isn't it: $r_1 - r = (b-q_1a) - (b-qa)= (b-q_1a) + (-b+qa) $, $\implies$ $(qa)-(q_1a)$, $\implies$ $a(q - q_1)$?

Comment: Your first two equalities are basically what I wrote. I don't understand the meaning of “$\therefore(qa)-(q_1a)$, $\therefore a(q-q_1)$”.

Comment: @JonathanKomar How can an equality imply a number?

Comment: @JonathanKomar And when is a number true? Or false, for that matter?

Comment: @JonathanKomar What happens is that$$r_1-r=(q_1-q)a\implies a\mid r_1-r,$$but that's what I wrote in my answer.

Comment: Assuming a number exists (true), and its identity can be represented in multiple ways, that I is what I intended. I can't really go back and change it to `=` now. Anyway, your result $(q_1-q)a$ is different than mine $(q-q_1)a$.

Comment: @JonathanKomar You are right. I've edited my answer.